# Should a retrieval method throw an exception when the index is out of range?

Tags: c++, exception, error-handling, throw

I have a method used between two processes that must return a register value (uint32_t) in case it exists, but I also need to return an error in case the passed index is out of range.

```
uint32_t getRegister(uint32_t index) {

    ...
}
```

I don't want to pass a pointer as an out parameter.
So, how can I do it? Can I throw an exception? Is there a better solution?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Compare with `vector`'s `operator[]` and `vector::at()`. The first doesn't through an exception the second does. It's up to the user to choose which one fits her needs. So bottom line, throwing or not throwing depends on your needs. Have also in mind, that out of bounds requires checking and this might slow down your application.

Comment: Consider just letting the function crash. If someone asks for a wrong index it is a bug that needs to be fixed, not an exception that needs to be caught. You can be nice and use `assert(index_is_valid);`.

Answer (score 0):

In case you can reserve a return value for an error situation 0 or 0xffffffff or something like that I think it's best to throw an exception.

I'd also add a method to check if an index is valid, in case some user would want to do exception free coding against this library, he'd know that a valid register is available. Something like:

```
bool isValidRegister(uint32_t index);
```